# Convert JavaScript String to Map Flutter

Tags: javascript, dart

I have a string like this:

```
'var key1 = "abcd"; var key2 ="xyz";'
```

and I want to convert this into the map or JSON, in Dart, like this:

```
{
'key1': 'abcd',
'key2': 'xyz'
}
```

Is there a way I can convert the J/S file as a string to a Dart map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate a `Map` form your string. You can use the help of  regular expressions ([online demo](https://regex101.com/r/mqtrGT/1)).

The following code captures two groups that are within the `()` and creates a `Map` out of them:

```dart
void main() {
  final s = 'var key1 = "abcd"; var key2 ="xyz"';
  
  final reg = RegExp(r'var (.*?)=\s?"(.*?)"');
  final myMap = Map.fromEntries(
      reg.allMatches(s).map((m) => MapEntry(m.group(1), m.group(2))));
  print(myMap);
}
```

Output:

```
{key1 : abcd, key2 : xyz}
```